# Training neural nets simultaneously in keras and have them share losses jointly while training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

Let's say I want to train three models simultaneously (model1, model2, and model3) and while training have the models one and two share losses jointly with the main network (model1). So the main model can learn representations from the two other models in between layers.

Loss total = (weight1)loss m1 + (weight2)(loss m1 - loss m2) + (weight3)(loss m1 - loss m3)

So far I have the following:

```
def threemodel(num_nodes, num_class, w1, w2, w3):
    #w1; w2; w3 are loss weights
    
    in1 = Input((6373,))
    enc1 = Dense(num_nodes)(in1)
    enc1 = Dropout(0.3)(enc1)
    enc1 = Dense(num_nodes, activation='relu')(enc1)
    enc1 = Dropout(0.3)(enc1)
    enc1 = Dense(num_nodes, activation='relu')(enc1)
    out1 = Dense(units=num_class, activation='softmax')(enc1)
    
    in2 = Input((512,))
    enc2 = Dense(num_nodes, activation='relu')(in2)
    enc2 = Dense(num_nodes, activation='relu')(enc2)    
    out2 = Dense(units=num_class, activation='softmax')(enc2)
    
    in3 = Input((768,))
    enc3 = Dense(num_nodes, activation='relu')(in3)
    enc3 = Dense(num_nodes, activation='relu')(enc3)    
    out3 = Dense(units=num_class, activation='softmax')(enc3)
    
    adam = Adam(lr=0.0001)

    
    model = Model(inputs=[in1, in2, in3], outputs=[out1, out2, out3])
    
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', #continu together
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'] not sure know what changes need to be made here)


## I am confused on how to formulate the shared losses equation here to share the losses of out2 and out3 with out1.
```

After searching a little it seems that can maybe do the following:

```
loss_1 = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true_1, out1)  
loss_2 = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true_2, out2)  
loss_3 = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true_3, out3)  

model.add_loss((w1)*loss_1 + (w2)*(loss_1 - loss_2) + (w3)*(loss_1 - loss_3))
```

Can this work? I feel like by doing what I suggested above is not really doing what I want which is to have the main model (mod1) learn representations from the two other models (mod2 and mod3) in between layers.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Some questions: weightX is expected to be trainable? The above models do not share other weights than the compound losses? Is the subtraction intended her: loss m1 - loss m2?

Comment: loss weights are not trainable. The models are just supposed to share the losses. I am trying to distill models 2 and 3 losses into model 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not interested in using trainable weights (I label them coefficients to distinguish them from trainable weights) you can concatenate the outputs and pass them as single output to a custom loss function. This means that those coefficients will be available when the training will start.

You should provide a custom loss function as mentioned. A loss function is expected to take 2 arguments only so you should such a function aka `categorical_crossentropy` which should also be familiar with the parameters you are interested also like `coeffs` and `num_class`. So I instantiate a wrapper function with the arguments I want and then pass the inside actual loss function as the main loss function.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Input, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import smart_cond
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K


def categorical_crossentropy_base(coeffs, num_class):

    def categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=False, label_smoothing=0):
        """Computes the categorical crossentropy loss.
      Args:
        y_true: tensor of true targets.
        y_pred: tensor of predicted targets.
        from_logits: Whether `y_pred` is expected to be a logits tensor. By default,
          we assume that `y_pred` encodes a probability distribution.
        label_smoothing: Float in [0, 1]. If > `0` then smooth the labels.
      Returns:
        Categorical crossentropy loss value.
        https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.15.0/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L938-L966
      """
        y_pred1 = y_pred[:, :num_class]  # the 1st prediction
        y_pred2 = y_pred[:, num_class:2*num_class]  # the 2nd prediction
        y_pred3 = y_pred[:, 2*num_class:]  # the 3rd prediction

        # you should adapt the ground truth to contain all 3 ground truth of course
        y_true1 = y_true[:, :num_class]  # the 1st gt
        y_true2 = y_true[:, num_class:2*num_class]  # the 2nd gt
        y_true3 = y_true[:, 2*num_class:]  # the 3rd gt

        loss1 = K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true1, y_pred1, from_logits=from_logits)
        loss2 = K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true2, y_pred2, from_logits=from_logits)
        loss3 = K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true3, y_pred3, from_logits=from_logits)

        # combine the losses the way you like it
        total_loss = coeffs[0]*loss1 + coeffs[1]*(loss1 - loss2) + coeffs[2]*(loss2 - loss3)
        return total_loss

    return categorical_crossentropy

in1 = Input((6373,))
enc1 = Dense(num_nodes)(in1)
enc1 = Dropout(0.3)(enc1)
enc1 = Dense(num_nodes, activation='relu')(enc1)
enc1 = Dropout(0.3)(enc1)
enc1 = Dense(num_nodes, activation='relu')(enc1)
out1 = Dense(units=num_class, activation='softmax')(enc1)

in2 = Input((512,))
enc2 = Dense(num_nodes, activation='relu')(in2)
enc2 = Dense(num_nodes, activation='relu')(enc2)
out2 = Dense(units=num_class, activation='softmax')(enc2)

in3 = Input((768,))
enc3 = Dense(num_nodes, activation='relu')(in3)
enc3 = Dense(num_nodes, activation='relu')(enc3)
out3 = Dense(units=num_class, activation='softmax')(enc3)

adam = Adam(lr=0.0001)

total_out = Concatenate(axis=1)([out1, out2, out3])
model = Model(inputs=[in1, in2, in3], outputs=[total_out])

coeffs = [1, 1, 1]
model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy_base(coeffs=coeffs, num_class=num_class),  optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am not sure about the metrics regarding accuracy though. But I think it will work without other changes. I am also using `K.categorical_crossentropy` but you can freely change it with another implementation as well of course.

Comment: In a model like the one you described above will it be able to fit the model like this? see below: 
` model.fit(x=[X_Train1, X_Train2, X_Train3], y=[Y_Train_Class1, Y_Train_Class2, Y_Train_Class3], batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=[(X_Valid1, Y_Valid_Class1), (X_Valid2, Y_Valid_Class2), (X_Valid3, Y_Valid_Class3)], verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks_list) `

Comment: you should be able to train your model providing 3 inputs if that's what you're asking